# decimal precision and scale:Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to set precision for all decimal fields in code first approach.for that

creating an Custom Attribute for this:

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public sealed class DecimalPrecisionAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public DecimalPrecisionAttribute(byte precision, byte scale)
        {
            Precision = precision;
            Scale = scale;

        }

        public byte Precision { get; set; }
        public byte Scale { get; set; }

    }
```

using

```
    [DecimalPrecision(20,10)]
    public Nullable<decimal> DeliveryPrice { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        foreach (Type classType in from t in Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(DecimalPrecisionAttribute)).GetTypes()
                                       where t.IsClass && t.Namespace == "YOURMODELNAMESPACE"
                                       select t)
         {
             foreach (var propAttr in classType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(p => p.GetCustomAttribute<DecimalPrecisionAttribute>() != null).Select(
                    p => new { prop = p, attr = p.GetCustomAttribute<DecimalPrecisionAttribute>(true) }))
             {

                 var entityConfig = modelBuilder.GetType().GetMethod("Entity").MakeGenericMethod(classType).Invoke(modelBuilder, null);
                 ParameterExpression param = ParameterExpression.Parameter(classType, "c");
                 Expression property = Expression.Property(param, propAttr.prop.Name);
                 LambdaExpression lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda(property, true,
                                                                          new ParameterExpression[]
                                                                              {param});
                 DecimalPropertyConfiguration decimalConfig;
                 if (propAttr.prop.PropertyType.IsGenericType && propAttr.prop.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
                 {
                     MethodInfo methodInfo = entityConfig.GetType().GetMethods().Where(p => p.Name == "Property").ToList()[7];
                     decimalConfig = methodInfo.Invoke(entityConfig, new[] { lambdaExpression }) as DecimalPropertyConfiguration;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     MethodInfo methodInfo = entityConfig.GetType().GetMethods().Where(p => p.Name == "Property").ToList()[6];
                     decimalConfig = methodInfo.Invoke(entityConfig, new[] { lambdaExpression }) as DecimalPropertyConfiguration;
                 }

                 decimalConfig.HasPrecision(propAttr.attr.Precision, propAttr.attr.Scale);
            }
        }
    }
```

But an error will be detected,

> Error    1   'System.Reflection.PropertyInfo' does not contain a definition for 'GetCustomAttribute' and no extension method 'GetCustomAttribute' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Reflection.PropertyInfo' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

How can i solve this?

Comment: Are you compiling for .NET 4.5? Because the extension method `GetCustomAttribute<T>(bool)` only exists in that version.

Comment: This is really a mystery for me how you can write elaborated reflection code but are not able to figure out the .NET version you are using.